# Definition of Holder space in Evan's book

Tags: partial-differential-equations

On page 255 of Evan's PDE book, the Holder space is defined to be the space for which $\lVert u\Vert_{C^{k,\gamma}(\bar U)}$ is finite.

However, on wikipedia and Gilberg&Trudinger, it only requires that $u$ is k'th order continuously differentiable and its k'th order partial derivatives are uniformly Holder continuous with exponent $\gamma$ in the domain. So, it doesn't demand that the sup norm of each derivatives are finite.

Is it common difference in convention? Or, do I misunderstand something?

Comment: If you want to have reasonable normed space, you want to follow Evans' convention. If you just want to define hölder continuous functions, the Gilbarg/Trudinger version is the way to go.

Comment: Consider continuous functions on $(0;1)$. You don't need to impose that they are bounded, but the sup-norm turns it into a nice normed space

Comment: At least good to know that I got the definition right.. Could you explain what you mean by "nice" and "reasonable" space?

Comment: By nice, I mean a Banach space. Of course you can consider other topologies on $C^0((0;1))$, you could turn it into a Frechet space (the metric in question would be induced by the the supremum norms on $(1/n; 1-1/n)$). What kind of norm/topology would you want to put on the space of continuous functions?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, although I feel like I lack the understanding of fundamental difference of those two conventions in terms of basic estimates involving schauder norm. Any insight?? Anyways, thanks so much!

Comment: If you wish to have estimates, you typically need reasonable norm.